# How to check whether a generic type implements a generic trait?

Tags: rust, template-specialization

I want to check whether a type implements a trait without creating an object. But it doesn't compile. See the comments in code . So what should I do to get my goal?

```
#![feature(specialization)]

struct T1;
struct T2;

trait A {}

impl A for T1 {}

trait Get_Static<TraitType> {
    fn has_trait() -> bool ;
}
default impl<TraitType, T> Get_Static<TraitType> for T
{
    fn has_trait() -> bool { false }
}
impl<TraitType, T> Get_Static<TraitType> for T where T:TraitType
{
    fn has_trait() -> bool { true }
}//Compiler complains TraitType is not a trait but type parameter

fn main() {
    if <T1 as Get_Static>::<A>::has_trait() {println!("{}", true)} else {println!("{}", false)}
    if <T2 as Get_Static>::<A>::has_trait() {println!("{}", true)} else {println!("{}", false)}
//This is surely wrong syntax but I don't know the right syntax
}
```

Comment: There is [`Unsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html) to check whether a type implements a trait; unfortunately this is [as far as I managed to go](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=56314071e6a9da620bb8a68f57dda595&version=nightly).

Comment: @MatthieuM. It still doesn't compile, and I don't know what does `<T1 as GetStatic<A>>` mean, are you creating an object or call "non-instance" method directly? Because I really don't want a T object...

Comment: If it compiled, I would have posted an answer. There is a reason that I mentioned "as far as I got" :) I'm hoping someone will be able to pick up where I left and get the ball rolling. As for `<Type as Trait>` it is a general syntax to obtain the `Trait` implementation for `Type`, which then allows you to call the associated functions of the `Trait`; in your case, you are asking for the trait `GetStatic<A>` as implemented for `T1`, thus `<T1 as GetStatic<A>>`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Try: `trait GetStatic<TraitType: ?Sized> {…}`

Comment: @Stefan: D'oh!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: this solution no longer works with recent nightly (2022-01), and it is unknown when it stopped working.**

---

*Thanks to Stefan who smoothed out the last wrinkle.*

> ```
> <T2 as Get_Static>::<A>::has_trait()
> ```

```
  //This is surely wrong syntax but I don't know the right syntax
```

This attempts to call:

- a trait associated function,
- implemented for a particular type.

The syntax is `<Type as Trait>::associated_function()`. In this case, `Type` is `T1`, `Trait` is `Get_Static<A>` so this should be:

```
<T2 as Get_Static<A>>::has_trait()
```

> ```
> impl<TraitType, T> Get_Static<TraitType> for T where T:TraitType
> {
>     fn has_trait() -> bool { true }
> }
> //Compiler complains TraitType is not a trait but type parameter
> ```

It is not possible, directly, to indicate that `TraitType` should be a `trait`, however the [`Unsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Unsize.html) marker can be used to check if `T: Unsize<TraitType>` which is sufficient for our purpose.

This requires 3 changes:

- enabling the nightly feature `#![feature(unsize)]` as the `Unsize` marker is unstable,
- allowing the `Get_Static` generic parameter to be `?Sized`, because traits are unsized,
- using `T: Unsize<TraitType>` as constraint in the implementation.

All told, this means:

```
#![feature(specialization)]
#![feature(unsize)]

trait GetStatic<TraitType: ?Sized> {
    fn has_trait() -> bool ;
}

default impl<TraitType: ?Sized, T> GetStatic<TraitType> for T {
    fn has_trait() -> bool { false }
}

impl<TraitType: ?Sized, T> GetStatic<TraitType> for T 
    where
        T: std::marker::Unsize<TraitType>
{
    fn has_trait() -> bool { true }
}
```

Which is then used as:

```
struct T1;
struct T2;

trait A {}

impl A for T1 {}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <T1 as GetStatic<A>>::has_trait());
    println!("{}", <T2 as GetStatic<A>>::has_trait());
}
```

[See it in action on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2c670db380a8f4d19e39393cf9438b64&version=nightly)

Comment: Thank you, I expand your code and failed again, so... any thoughts? https://gist.github.com/Xtricman/bf184572e557472c5f67e645c0a7d973

Comment: @神秘德里克: I doubt the cast is possible at the moment. As I mentioned, Rust generics do not have *kinds*, and therefore `TraitType` is never as a trait. The `Unsize` trick is a round-about way, and not totally fool-proof either as you could use any other unsized type than a trait. I managed to make it work without the `'a` [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=67a72b30035d446e942cee9c2494bb46&version=nightly), though I am not sure how useful that is.

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: @codyoss: Indeed; not sure if that's a bug in rustc, or if the specialization rules changed... that's the issue of using nightly.